# Schema for separate SKU table and product table

Tags: schema, database-schema, business-logic

Can someone suggest me a schema when I want to have a separate product table and SKU table... reason for this is when I want to do product bundle

SKU1 contains product_A + product_B

SKU2 contains product_A

SKU3 contains product_B

When SKU1 is sold it deducts inventory for product_A and product_B
When SKU2 is sold it deducts to product_A only

Answer (score 0):

A simple schema that meets your requirements is

```
CREATE TABLE SKUS 
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
SKU VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT 
)

CREATE TABLE SKU_PRODUCTS
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
SKUID INT,
PRODUCTID INT,
CONSTRAINT FK_SKU_Products_Skus FOREIGN KEY (SKUID) REFERENCES SKUS (ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_Sku_products_Products FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES PRODUCTS (ID)
CONSTRAINT UC_SKU_Prodcts_skuid_product_id UNIQUE (SKUID, PRODUCTID)
```

)

You define a table for skus, a table for products, and a many-to-many lookup table relating skus to products. I would also suggest your primary keys be auto increments.

Comment: If I wanted to know my current stock then I'll run query based on PRODUCTS table, when I want to process order, it will get from SKUS table? Then when I want to enter a new stock arrival, it will be entered thru PRODUCTS table? For my product price, it will be pricing on SKU table instead of PRODUCTS table?